# How to read large file from Amazon S3?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, guava

I have a program which will read a textfile from Amazon s3, but the file is around 400M. I have increased my Heap size but i'm still getting the Java Heap Size error. So, I'm not sure if my code is correct or not. I'm using Amazon SDK for java and Guava to deal with the file stream.

Please help

```
        S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, folder + filename));
        final InputStream objectData = object.getObjectContent();

        InputSupplier supplier = CharStreams.newReaderSupplier(new InputSupplier() {
            @Override
            public InputStream getInput() throws IOException {
                return objectData;
            }
        }, Charsets.UTF_8);

        String content = CharStreams.toString(supplier);
        objectData.close();

        return content;
```

I use this option for my JVM. `-Xms512m -Xmx2g`. I use ant to run the main program so I include the jvm option to ANT_OPTS as well. But it's still not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point of `InputSupplier` -- though you should be using `ByteSource` and `CharSource` these days -- is that you should never have access to the `InputStream` from the outside, so you don't have to remember to close it or not.

If you're using an old version of Guava before `ByteSource` and `CharSource` were introduced, then this should be

```
    InputSupplier supplier = CharStreams.newReaderSupplier(new InputSupplier() {
        @Override
        public InputStream getInput() throws IOException {
           S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(
             new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, folder + filename));
           return object.getObjectContent();
        }
    }, Charsets.UTF_8);
    String content = CharStreams.toString(supplier);
```

If you're using Guava 14, then this can be done more fluently as

```
    new ByteSource() {
      @Override public InputStream openStream() throws IOException {
        S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(
            new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, folder + filename));
        return object.getObjectContent();
      }
    }.asCharSource(Charsets.UTF_8).read();
```

That said: your file might be 400MB, but Java `String`s are stored as UTF-16, which can easily double its memory consumption.  You may either need lots more memory, or you need to figure out a way to avoid keeping the whole file in memory at once.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than taking whole file in memory you can read file by parts so your whole file will not been in memory . Avoid taking whole file in memory so that you wont get memory issue because of limited memory

```
GetObjectRequest rangeObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key);
rangeObjectRequest.setRange(0, 1000); // retrieve 1st 1000 bytes.
S3Object objectPortion = s3Client.getObject(rangeObjectRequest);
InputStream objectData = objectPortion.getObjectContent();
```

//Go in loop now and make file locally by reading content from s3 and append file in loop so there wont be whole content in memory